# Azure Notification Hubs in C++ apps?

Tags: c++, windows, azure, uwp, notifications

In Microsoft documentation there is the example for C# implementation of Azure Notification Hubs -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#create-a-sample-windows-app

```
private async void InitNotificationsAsync()
{
    var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

    var hub = new NotificationHub("<your hub name>", "<Your DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature connection string>");
    var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);

    // Displays the registration ID so you know it was successful
    if (result.RegistrationId != null)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Registration successful: " + result.RegistrationId);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

but our app use C++ and we found part of example code in WinRT/C++ documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.pushnotifications.pushnotificationchannelmanager?view=winrt-22621

...but without part of Azure code:

```
var hub = new NotificationHub("<your hub name>", "<Your DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature connection string>");
```

Is it means that for apps with bare C++ Azure Messaging is impossible theme?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum nope, but how noticed Thiago Custodio in his answer you can use REST API

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, only a few Azure Services can be used using the c++ SDK. You can check in here:

https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/cpp_introduction.html

However, you can interact directly to the REST Api:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/create-update-registration